# Merging two list of dictionaries according to a key value in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have two list of dictionaries. I want to merge them according to a specific key.

Here is list1:

```
"list1": [
  { "a": "b", "c": "d" },
  { "a": "e", "c": "f" }
]
```

Here is list2:

```
"list2": [
  { "a": "e", "g": "h" },
  { "a": "b", "g": "i" }
]
```

So after merging the final list of dictionaries should look like below. The merging should be done according the value of key "a":

```
"list3": [
  { "a": "b", "c": "d", "g": "i" },
  { "a": "e", "c": "f", "g": "h" }
]
```

Official documentation seems not enough for loops, iteration etc. I couldn't find a way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple option is to *reverse* the second list and *combine* the *zip* of the lists

```yaml
  list3: "{{ list1|zip(list2|reverse)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list3:
    - {a: b, c: d, g: i}
    - {a: e, c: f, g: h}
```

---

The next option is to iterate the first list. In the loop select the items from the second list and combine them. The expression below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ list3|d([]) + [item|combine(_selection)] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
      vars:
        _selection: "{{ list2|selectattr('a', '==', item.a)|combine }}"
```

You can use *json_query* instead of *selectattr* if you want to

```yaml
      vars:
        _selection: "{{ list2|json_query(_query)|combine }}"
        _query: '[?a==`{{ item.a }}`]'
```

---

If you can install the collection [community.general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html#community-general) use the filter [*lists_mergeby*](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries).  The expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  list3: "{{ list1|lists_mergeby(list2, 'a') }}"
```

If you're not able to install the collection create a custom filter on your own. For example

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/my_lists_mergeby.py
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter


def my_lists_mergeby(l1, l2, index):

    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for l in (l1, l2):
        for elem in l:
            if index in elem.keys():
                d[elem[index]].update(elem)
    return sorted(d.values(), key=itemgetter(index))


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'my_lists_mergeby': my_lists_mergeby,
        }
```

Comment: I cannot know the order of lists, so first option is not applicable for this case. also i don't have privilege to install a module from community library. but second one seems applicable. i've tried it but got the following error: original message: |combine expects dictionaries, got <generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7fbedec5bfa0>"... it gave the error for this part: "{{ list2|selectattr('a', '==', item.a)|combine }}"

Comment: I see. The combination of the list's items was added only recently. If you have an older version get the filter [*lists_mergeby*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/community.general/main/plugins/filter/list.py) and put it into your *plugins* directory. You'll have to edit it.

Comment: Yes Vladimir, i've checked and saw that i have jinja2 version 2.7. i'll follow your last suggestion. i'm accepting your first answer. Thank you. i'll edit here if necessary.

Comment: I updated the answer with a tested custom filter.

Comment: Vladimir, can we use json_query() besides of selectattr()? for example like: _selection: "{{ list2 | json_query('\"[a==' + item.a + ']\"') | combine }}"

Comment: As my environment's version is not enough high to use selectattr comparison in Vladimis's answer, i modified his answer to use with json_query. it also works well with jinja 2.7.

vars:
   _selection: "{{ list2|json_query(a_query)|combine }}"
  a_query: "[?a==`{{item.a}}`]"

Vladimir, maybe you can update the answer if it's also ok for you.

Comment: I updated the *json_query* option. Thank you.