# Ansible combine two results based on the key

Tags: ansible, data-manipulation

If someone can suggest a resource to self educate, would be much appreciated. At the moment I am learning by examples based on what works. Sorry if the terminology is incorrect

I have two results in json format (dictionary?) from the commands sent to Netscaler API:

Result1 lists certificate information:

```json
{
        "errorcode": 0,
        "message": "Done",
        "severity": "NONE",
        "sslcertkey": [
            {
                "certkey": "certkey1.pair",
                "daystoexpiration": 0,
                "status": "Expired",
                "subject": "easdm.test.com"
            },
            {
                "certkey": "certkey2.pair",
                "daystoexpiration": 0,
                "status": "Expired",
                "subject": " CN=timer.test.com"
            },
```

Result2 lists which certificate is bound to a virtual server:

```json
{
        "errorcode": 0,
        "message": "Done",
        "severity": "NONE",
        "sslcertkey_sslvserver_binding": [
            {
                "certkey": "certkey1.pair",
                "data": "1",
                "servername": "easdm_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs",
                "stateflag": "2",
                "version": 1
            },
            {
                "certkey": "certkey2.pair",
                "data": "2",
                "servername": "timer_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs",
                "stateflag": "2",
                "version": 1
            },
```

I want to combine two results into Result3, so that it will combine info from Result1 with Result2 if "certkey" is matching between the results:

```json
    {
        "certkey": "certkey1.pair",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "status": "Expired",
        "subject": "easdm.test.com",
        "servername": "easdm_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs"
    },
    {
        "certkey": "certkey2.pair",
        "daystoexpiration": 0,
        "status": "Expired",
        "subject": " CN=timer.test.com",
        "servername": "timer_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs"
    },
```

There are 100's of entries in each result and some results in Result1 will not have a match in Result2 as cert is not used anywhere.
I tried using just a simple

```yaml
    - debug:
         msg: '{{ result.json.sslcertkey | combine(result2.json.sslcertkey_sslvserver_binding, recursive=True)  }}'
```

but it seem to only show the last match and not all of the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries)

```yaml
  result3: "{{ result1.sslcertkey|
               community.general.lists_mergeby(result2.sslcertkey_sslvserver_binding,
                                               'certkey') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result3:
  - certkey: certkey1.pair
    data: '1'
    daystoexpiration: 0
    servername: easdm_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs
    stateflag: '2'
    status: Expired
    subject: easdm.test.com
    version: 1
  - certkey: certkey2.pair
    data: '2'
    daystoexpiration: 0
    servername: timer_gslb_btfin_pri_lb_vs
    stateflag: '2'
    status: Expired
    subject: ' CN=timer.test.com'
    version: 1
```

Comment: Would have been fantastic, but...needs Ansible 2.10 =(
We are running ansible 2.9.2 still

Comment: See [Merging two lists of dictionaries according to a key value in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627339/merging-two-list-of-dictionaries-according-to-a-key-value-in-ansible/70627911#70627911). Create the filter on your own.